# How to decrease xmlattribute id by one after deleting node in c#

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a c# console application where I have to save data to XML through serialization, so far it works, I can edit single nodes and delete them. My problem is that I have an id Attribute for each node, which I made "unique" with a trick. Every time I save data to my XML I count a list and then add + 1 to the current count that was my Id, it worked at first good but after deleting a data and then adding another one, I have the problem of two datasets having the same Id. How could I make it that the ids will decrease by 1 after deleting a data or double-checking if an attribute has a specific value and then automatically give a different id?

this is my code where I save the data and id:

public  bool saveCustomer()

```
{
    string filePath = "customerDatabase2.xml";
    serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
    List<Kunde> kList = new List<Kunde>();
    var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Namen des Kunden ein!");
    string firstNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Nachnamen des Kunden ein!");
    string lastNameInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Adresse des Kunden ein!");
    string adressInput =  Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Geburtsdatum des Kunden ein!");
    string birthdayInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie den Bankdetails des Kunden ein!");
    string bankDetailsInput = Console.ReadLine();

    kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>), filePath) as List<Kunde>;

    int id = (from XElement i in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Kunde") select int.Parse(i.Attribute("id").Value)).Max() + 1;


    Kunde customer = new Kunde(id,firstNameInput, lastNameInput, adressInput, birthdayInput, bankDetailsInput,buchung);
    Console.Clear();

        if (File.Exists("customerDatabase2.xml"))
        {
            kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>), filePath) as List<Kunde>;
            

        }


        kList.Add(customer);

        sHelper.XmlSerialize(typeof(List<Kunde>), kList, filePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Ihr Kunde wurde gespeichert danke für die Zusammenarbeit!");

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Drücken Sie 1 um ins Hauptmenü zu gelangen und auf 2 um die Applikation zu beenden!");
        Program p = new Program();


        switch (Console.ReadLine())
        {
            case "1": Program.menuPoints(); return true;
            case "2": Environment.Exit(0); return true;
           
        }
        return true;
    }
```

this is my delete method:

```
public void delete()
        {
            string filepath = "customerdatabase2.xml";
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            Console.WriteLine(xDoc);
            Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Id des Kunden an, den Sie löschen möchten!");
            var tgt = xDoc.Root.Descendants("Kunde").FirstOrDefault(x =>
            x.Attribute("id").Value == Console.ReadLine());

            tgt.Remove();
            xDoc.Save(filepath);
        idTester();

            Console.WriteLine("Kunde wurde gelöscht!");
        }
```

this is how my xml looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfKunde xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Kunde id="2">
    <firstName>sdfc</firstName>
    <lastName>nbv</lastName>
    <adress>bjk</adress>
    <birthday>hjvn</birthday>
    <bankDetails>jhgj</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
  <Kunde id="3">
    <firstName>mbn,</firstName>
    <lastName>hgj</lastName>
    <adress>ghj</adress>
    <birthday>ghjg</birthday>
    <bankDetails>hghj</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
  <Kunde id="3">
    <firstName>n</firstName>
    <lastName>lh</lastName>
    <adress>lkj</adress>
    <birthday>lkj</birthday>
    <bankDetails>lj</bankDetails>
  </Kunde>
</ArrayOfKunde>
```

EDIT ADD CODE:

```
public void idTester()
        {
            serializerHelper sHelper = new serializerHelper();
            List<Kunde> kList = new List<Kunde>();

            string filepath = "customerdatabase2.xml";
            var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
            kList = sHelper.showData(typeof(List<Kunde>), filepath) as List<Kunde>;
        int index = 0; 
        List<XElement> Kundes = xDoc.Descendants("Kunde").ToList(); 
        foreach (var Kunde in Kundes) 
        { 
            Kunde.SetAttributeValue("id", ++index); 
        }
        xDoc.Save(filepath);



        }
```

Comment: Best way is to renumber the entire list starting at one.

Comment: so you mean after deleting one node to count the list and give them each Id's again?

Comment: Yes.  It becomes complicated to add numbers in a middle of a list.  So when possible the easiest method is just to renumber the entire list.

Comment: could you maybe give me an example I am kinda stuck right now do not know how to start... I will add what I did so far I do not know if I have to work with xDoc or with the list to be honest

Comment: int index = 0; List<XElement> Kundes = doc.Descendants("Kunde").ToList();  foreach(var Kunde in Kundes) { Kunde.SetAttributeValue("id",++index);}

Comment: Hi edited my code and put your code inside but it does not work. I am calling this method after I delete (which happens in another method) and save the doc.

Comment: You didn't add int index = 0;

Comment: no I did haha it is over Kundes = xDoc...

Comment: Yes you do!!!  Where is the value of index?  Kunde.SetAttributeValue("id",++index)

Comment: it is inside the for each brackets if I understood you correctly

Comment: You need index to increment exactly like the code I posted.  Your code doesn't have a value for index.

Comment: sorry I am really confused right now, the value for index is 0 or not? int index = 0

Comment: It increments each loop

Comment: yes and this is done with the forEach loop right? So did I copy your code correctly?

Comment: I just test code to renumber and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about a unique ID. The correct way would be to assign each number only once, regardless of deleted entries. To achieve this you need to save your last ID separatedly. When you add a new entry it recieves the actual ID and you increment it by one.

```
static class XmlEditor
{
    static int id;

    ... // some initialization needed. For example load the current id from a file


    static public bool saveCustomer()
    {
        ...

        Kunde customer = new Kunde(id,firstNameInput, lastNameInput, adressInput, birthdayInput, bankDetailsInput);
        id++;

        ...

    }
}
```

This way you'll never have the same number twice. This also simulates the way a autoincremented primary key works in a database.

To get the next ID you can search your XDocument, pick the highest id and increment it by one

```
int id = (from XElement i in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Kunde") select int.Parse(i.Attribute("id").Value)).Max()+1;
```

**EDIT:**

I have tested this and came up with this. I hope it helps

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument();
    doc.Add(new XElement("Kunden"));
    for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
    {
        AddNewKunde(doc.Root);
    }
    PrintKunden(doc.Root);
    RemoveKunde(doc.Root, 2);
    PrintKunden(doc.Root);

    AddNewKunde(doc.Root);
    PrintKunden(doc.Root);

    Console.ReadLine();
       
}

private static void AddNewKunde(XElement parent)
{
    int id = 0;
    if (parent.Elements().Count() > 0)
    {
        id = (from XElement xe in parent.Elements("Kunde") select int.Parse(xe.Attribute("id").Value)).Max() + 1;
    }

    parent.Add(new XElement("Kunde", new XAttribute("id", id)));
}

private static void RemoveKunde(XElement parent, int id)
{
    parent.Elements("Kunde").Single(x => x.Attribute("id").Value == id.ToString()).Remove();
}

private static void PrintKunden(XElement parent)
{
    foreach (XElement e in parent.Elements())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine("=====");
}
```

Output:

```
<Kunde id="0" />
<Kunde id="1" />
<Kunde id="2" />
<Kunde id="3" />
=====
<Kunde id="0" />
<Kunde id="1" />
<Kunde id="3" />
=====
<Kunde id="0" />
<Kunde id="1" />
<Kunde id="3" />
<Kunde id="4" />
=====
```

Comment: Hi, What do you mean with initilization and load current Id from file? The latest entry of id?

Comment: Maybe I was thinking ahead. If you plan to edit your xml File at separate times you need to have the ID saved somewhere. For example in a separate File or the application.exe.config

Comment: no this is just a simple school project in order to show we can use c# there is no need for ids even I just thought it would simplify for me a few things

Comment: to avoid having another file you could look into all existing Kunde elements and pick the highest id you find. I'll modify my answer accordingly

Comment: Hi I added this line: int id = (from XElement i in xDoc.Root.Descendants("Kunde") select int.Parse(i.Attribute("id").Value)).Max()+1;
It kinda works. But in the second add. So for example if the highest id is 3 it will first add another kunde with id 3 and then if I add another one it will add one with 4. I will add my code to show how I did it.

Comment: And I noticed one more thing, if I delete for example every kunde with my method. And then add 2 kunde. I can not delete them anymore like it can not find the id even though it shows it. It only works when I first delete the first added kunde and then the second one